# What does mean annotation without any params in java?

Tags: java, annotations, functional-interface

I' m trying to understand @Functional interface from JDK and can't catch why did they create this annotation without a body?

I don't understand what is difference between using @FunctionalInterface in class description and not using? what does this annotation without params provide?

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface FunctionalInterface {}
```

Comment: All functional interfaces are recommended to have an informative @FunctionalInterface annotation. This not only clearly communicates the purpose of this interface, but also allows a compiler to generate an error if the annotated interface does not satisfy the conditions. See https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces

Comment: `@FunctionalInterface` annotation is used to ensure an interface can’t have more than one abstract method. The use of this annotation is optional.

Comment: It is purely a _marker_ interface, to signal that some annotated interface is intended to be used/usable as lambda, that it contains just _one_ function. Containing one function would mean calling `getDeclaredMethods` for counting, which is  an unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add it, someone won't be able to add more methods without breaking your [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) and will get a compile time error:

```
Invalid '@FunctionalInterface' annotation; MyInterface is not a functional interface
```

> If a type is annotated with this annotation type, compilers are required to generate an error message unless:
>
> - The type is an interface type and not an annotation type, enum, or class.
> - The annotated type satisfies the requirements of a functional interface.